# Profitability Of Radeon RX 580 (8gb) for mining Ethereum

Tags: mining, gpu

I have gone to about half a dozen or more "Profitability" Calculators for mining Ethereum and the majority of them all say that you can realistically make $2.10 to $2.40 a day off of one Radeon RX 580 (8GB), but I wanted to come here to double-check first with people who actually mine Ethereum on a day to day basis and know the statistics on whether or not this is a realistic and accurate price for a 580. Throwing electricity costs, wear and tear mining pool fees, and all of that out the window, I was just wondering if these numbers are correct and if not, what would be a more accurate number for a Radeon RX 580.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have mining experience, but I know that: Mining rewards are not stable. It depends on how much transactions happening and Ethereum price. And Ethereum Foundation trying to decrease mining fees.